# Which approach is better for creating an Android alias resource?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

When studying about Android alias resources, I encountered different approaches for creating an alias and determining its destination type.

In the first approach, as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters), we determine the destination type via a `type` attribute inside an `<item>` tag. For instance, here we declare that the alias is pointing to a layout resource:

```
<resources>
    <item name="main" type="layout">@layout/main_twopanes</item>
</resources>
```

In the second approach, as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AliasResources), we determine the destination via a specific tag (instead of `<item>`). For instance, here we declare that the alias is pointing to a drawable resource:

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="icon">@drawable/icon_ca</drawable>
</resources>
```

Or, where things get more complicated, here we set the destination to be a layout:

```
<merge>
    <include layout="@layout/main_ltr"/>
</merge>
```

What is the difference between these approaches?

Are they identical, or differ in a way that I'm missing?

When should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: The `<include>` approach is not really an alias. `<include>` is for where you have a common layout XML block that you want to insert into 2+ other layouts. The `<item>` approach is most general-purpose approach, as AFAIK that works for all resource types.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I wonder why Google, in its official guide for creating alias resources, has used such an inconsistent approach. Using <include> tag in a <merge> element for layouts, while using <drawable>, <string> or <color> tag inside <resources> element for other resources. And not even mentioning the <item> tag approach inside a <resources> element. It's very confusing and IMO inconsistent.

Comment: "It's very confusing and IMO inconsistent" -- that is a common theme with the Android documentation. Eventually, you get used to it.